# Task.WhenAny blocking

Tags: c#, async-await, task, blocking

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the usage of Task.WhenAny but in the following code only "0" gets printed when it should print "1" and "2" and then "mx.Name" every time a task finishes:

```
public async void PopulateMxRecords(List<string> nsRecords, int threads)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(threads, threads);
        var resolver = new DnsStubResolver();
        var tasks = nsRecords.Select(ns => resolver.ResolveAsync<MxRecord>(ns, RecordType.Mx));

        Console.WriteLine("0");
        var finished = Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("1");

        while (mxNsRecords.Count < nsRecords.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
            var task = await finished;
            var mxRecords = await task;
            foreach(var mx in mxRecords)
                Console.WriteLine(mx.Name);
        }
    }
```

The DnsStubResolver is part of ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns. The nsRecords list contains up to 2 million strings.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The task returned by `Task.WhenAny` completes when one of your DNS lookup tasks complete. Normally you would await that for control flow and you also do that but many times in a loop. Subsequent awaits does nothing as the task is already complete.

Comment: In the end i will add all the tasks to a list and then remove tasks from the list as they complete and add the result to mxNsRecords. This code is just for testing but it should still print out "1" and "2" before Task.WhenAny completes.

Comment: If your code prints `0` but not `1` then it must be busy doing the enumeration of the `tasks` enumerable. Based on the information in your question I can't figure out why but you are reconfiguring the thread pool, using a library that for all we know might do async over sync and perhaps trying to start two million tasks at the same time so I would investigate that and not focus on a surprising way to use `Task.WhenAny`.

Comment: The reason I'm reconfiguring the threadpool is beacuse it only uses 4 threads by default and i noticed a significant increase in resolved records per second when i increased it in a similar setup. The problem is most likely as you said that it's busy doing the enumeration of the tasks enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the usage of Task.WhenAny

You might be. The pattern you seem to be looking for is [interleaving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern#interleaving). In the following example, notice the important changes that I have made:

1. use `ToList()` to materialize the LINQ query results,
2. move `WhenAny()` into the loop,
3. use `Remove(task)` as each task completes, and
4. run the while loop as long as `tasks.Count() > 0`.

Those are the important changes. The other changes are there to make your listing into a runnable demo of interleaving, the full listing of which is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nr1gQ7

```
public static async Task PopulateMxRecords(List<string> nsRecords)
{
    var tasks = nsRecords.Select(ns => ResolveAsync(ns)).ToList();

    while (tasks.Count() > 0)
    {
        var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(task);

        var mxRecords = await task;
        Console.WriteLine(mxRecords);
    }
}
```